# Where can I see amount of Azure Storage Accounts File Share burst IOPS spent or left?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files

Where can I see amount of Azure Storage Accounts File Share burst IOPS spent or left?

I went through service Monitoring > Insights, but was not able to find such metric.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage does not have a concept of credits. You use, and pay for, as much as you use. You can see costs that have been generated by your resources using [Azure Cost Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cost-management/) in the portal.

Comment: First, thanks for fast response! Probably i used wrong terminology, how can I see how much burst IO have I spent for my file share - https://prnt.sc/utb6wy, https://prnt.sc/utb6wy?